# URL rewriting going from www.example.com/blog/blog.php to just www.example.com/blog/

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

I have a site that to get to the blog section I have www.example.com/blog/blog.php and I would like it to use www.example.com/blog/    The folder structure I have is that blog.php is inside a folder called blog.  Do I just rewrite the blog.php to be blog and add it to the top level?

Comment: What sort of web server you are using?

Comment: @ajreal apache, php as the scripting language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it you want to show `blog.php` if user typed `www.example.com/blog/` in the address bar. You would try renaming `blog.php` to `index.php` (You didn't provided any extra information about your web server; I assume it loads `index.php` as start page by default).

Comment: oh, that will most likely work.  I thought about doing this, wasn't at home to test it out, thanks!~